# Expanding Circle on Sphere Surface

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I'm trying to animate an expanding circle as a texture on a sphere.  I've tried using a wave texture, but that doesn't seem to be working.  It has to start as a point (very small circle), then expand out a little way like a rock dropped in a pond (with no waves) and then disappear.  The coordinates it starts on as well as its maximum size has to be random and repeat.  It has to fade out at maximum size.

I'm stumped.  Can this be done with anything but a custom written procedural?

Thanks!

Comment: It's fairly simple to make one sequence animated manually, but changing location in repetitive manner could be quite tedious (by hand). If you want I can make an answer with manual setup - only one sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: circle texture demo]

Use a gradient node and modify its color with a ramp node.

[image: sphere texture nodes]

Then drive its location with an empty.

[image: empty driver]

Comment: That's great, could you mark the answer as accepted?